# Liveware component not updating whole DOM

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a laravel component that switches to multiple views.
Imagine I have these 2 views:

**View 1**

```
<div class='progress-bar'>
<h1>View 1</h1>
```

**View 2**

```
<div class='progress-bar'>
<h1>View 1</h1>
```

On a button click, the component changes from View 1 to View 2.
Now the progress bar in there is using a css animation to load itself, but since the DOM code is very similar, the progress bar doesn't change, and even after a view change, the progress bar retains its position rather than resetting.

I want the progress bar to reset too.

If I change the markup of the progress bar in any way like:

**View 2**

```
<div>
    <div class='progress-bar'>
</div>
<h1>View 1</h1>
```

That fixes the problem, but I'd prefer not to do that.

**Anyway I can force liveware to render everything in the other view from scratch?**

Comment: You probably need to add `wire:key="view1"` and `wire:key="view2"` Also, there's a good explanation on the doc https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/troubleshooting

Comment: Yup, that fixed it, I gave it an id as well, and that fixed it too, but I'm guessing the wire:key is a much better way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Giving it an id, or a wire:key as pointed out by Clement does the trick.